# Quotient of variety by additive group separated?

Tags: geometric-invariant-theory

I have some sub variety of a complex flag variety and I want to take the quotient by a free action of $\mathbb{C}$.
I know that this quotient exists locally as a variety. My question is whether there are general results or criteria, which guarantee, that if I patch the local quotients together the result is again separated. 
I know that this is true for reductive groups.